# Magento 1.9 huge TTFB

Tags: magento-1.9, pagespeed

I'm running my store on a Magento 1.9.2.4 installation and after installing a new theme it took ~55 seconds to load but with few changes it went down to ~8 seconds(which is still too much).

So i started searching for an answer and i found a post about TTFB. In my case it is around 4.5 sec(which is ... a lot).

[image]

Is there something i can do to fix this(at least cut it in half, instead of ~8sec to bring it down to ~4)?

I have a VPS server from Digital Ocean which has:

```
Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Apache/2.4.7
MySQL innodb_version 5.5.41
```

So far i've done this:

1. Edit .htaccess file to activate compression(mod_deflate)
2. Activate Cache(and flush them and etc.)
3. Catalog to flat category/product
4. Merge Css/Js

Store specifications:

```
Magento 1.9.2.4
SKU 45.000
```

P.S: With the default theme and 45.000 products the store goes pretty smooth(~two seconds to load)

P.S.S: After @Haim recommended AOE Profiler i've managed to open one of the scans. Here it is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is in your question, there's something about your theme that's causing that poor performance.

You didn't provide the theme name, but at least now you know for the future that a theme is not just about what it looks like, it's about how well the code is implemented.

A typical thing that we found with themes is features such as New or featured products that load the entire collection (45,000 items in your case) and then filter out the products they want to show.

Something else that we find quite often are themes that have many settings and the theme code is riddled with if this or that setting.

Can you confirm that the TTFB is just as bad on **every** page? Home page, list page, product page etc?

Your best bet would be to use [AOE Profiler](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Profiler) and drill down till you find the actual culprit. I think you'll find it right away.

Comment: Hey @Haim, the loading speed is ~8 sec on the front page, when you load the website, then if you click on a product it's ~5 sec and then if you click back on the home page it's ~8 sec. The theme name is "Porto"(from themeforest.net) :(

Comment: @emma a quick look at their documentation shows they have a licence check and all those product collections on the homepage... Did you try using the profiler?

Comment: Hey @Haim, i'm "playing" with profiler right now(AEO_Profiler - the one you recommended) and i have a problem: when i click on one of the logs that is related to the admin area and has 12MB it's ok, i can see the files and their loading times and all that data but when i click on the log related to `index.php?profile=1` it has 86MB and it opens the log but doesn't show me anything maybe because of the database? Help :-s

Comment: P.S: When i do `SELECT * FROM aoe_profiler_run WHERE id=X` (x being the log id) in Putty i get a very long result(86mb i guess) but the point is that i get it but of course it is not readable :(

Comment: If you want to debug the homepage first then I suggest you first remove all those blocks that load collections first

Comment: Hmm ok but which blocks load collections? X_X

Comment: See here http://www.portotheme.com/magento/porto/documentation/ - look for the section "How to show products in homepage?"

Comment: i think i found the problems, can you please take a look above, i've edited my question adding a screen shot of the profile

Comment: I can't see the timing on your screenshot but the `mobilemenu.phtml`,`sidemenu.phtml` and `sidemobilemenu.phtml`  look problematic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85081/discussion-between-haim-and-emma).

Answer (score 0):

one more aspect that can help you speed up your Magento site is to optimize your images.

A catalog containing 45,000 images ( assuming you have 1 image per product ) requires rendering of these images again & again whenever the user visits your site.

To improve your performance, you can serve cached images ( using CDN ) or optimize images based on the user's browser requests.

You can check here [Website Analyser](https://imagekit.io/website-analyzer) to know more about the images that are being loaded.

I hope this helps you :)